# GIS integration with SWMM

Tags: qgis, pipe-network, swmm

I am interested in producing input files for [SWMM](https://www.epa.gov/water-research/storm-water-management-model-swmm) from GIS data, hopefully from QGIS. Does any one know a free tool to do it?

I found this plug-in [qgis-swmm](https://github.com/Oslandia/qgis-swmm), but I do not see it in the repository of plugins. Does it work?

Answer (score 3):

Do you know GISWater?

https://www.giswater.org/

or ImportEpanetInpFiles? plugin for QGIS 3

https://github.com/KIOS-Research/ImportEpanetInpFiles

Answer (score 1):

I have recently read about the plugin QGEP

> A waste-water application based on QGIS in compliance with SIA-405.

[link to QGEP on github](https://github.com/QGEP/QGEP)

I have not tried yet

Answer (score 0):

this will be available in the QGIS plugin repository soon:
https://github.com/Jannik-Schilling/generate_swmm_inp